# How to switch between tabs and perform some operation and switch back to parent tab?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to switch to new tab, perform some operation in the child tab and return back to parent tab?

In my below code its taking to new tab, performing the action. But the parent tab(yahoo) got the same session as in child tab(gmail)

Here is my code:

```java
driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com");

ReadExcell.setExcelFile(Constant.filepath + Constant.fileName, "Sheet1");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
String parentwindow=driver.getWindowHandle();

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.open('http://www.gmail.com','_blank');");

Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles();

System.out.println("windows count is " +s1.size());

for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
{
    driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

    String str=winHandle.toString();

    System.out.println("The tostring value is" +str);
    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
    String Email=ReadExcell.getCellData(10, 1);
    String Pwd=ReadExcell.getCellData(10, 2);
    GmailLogin.Emailid(driver).sendKeys(Email);
    GmailLogin.next(driver).click();
    GmailLogin.Password(driver).sendKeys(Pwd);
    GmailLogin.Pwdnext(driver).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    //System.out.println("Window count is" +winHandle());
}
driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parentwindow);

System.out.println(parentwindow);
System.out.println("Ater switching title is ="+driver.getTitle());
```

Is there any other way to name each tab and goto the corresponding tab perform some action and go back to parent tab? your help will be more helpful....
Note: I am using mac

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
public void switchToWindow(int index){
    Set<String> windows = driver.getWindowHandles();
    driver.switchTo().window((String) windows.toArray()[index]);
}
```

Usage:

```
switchToWindow(1); // Switch to new window
doSomething();
switchToWindow(0); // Switch back to original window
```

Comment: I tried your code but its again loading the same session in the first tab as in tab2

Comment: That's because you are not signed off and still use the same browser. You need to sign off or start another driver session for a clean start.